# Zonal Statistics R

Tags: r, polygon, raster, geography, r-raster

I use the `raster` package in `R` und perform an `extract` on a raster with `shapefile` that contains several `polygons` (200). Each polygon has a column where the `class` of the polygon is specified.
When I perform the `extract` I get a `dataframe` where each value of the raster is "assigned" to a polygon: In which polygon is which pixel located. However, the information that my polygon contains (i.e. what classes the are), are gone. My dataframe after the `extract` looks something like:

```
test <- extract(myRaster, myTrainingPolygon, df = TRUE)

ID     band1     band2    band3
1      0.101     0.827    ...
...    ...       ...      ...
200    0.876     0.821    ...
```

What I need is something like

```
ID     band1     band2    band3    class
1      0.101     0.827    ...      class1
...    ...       ...      ...      ...
200    0.876     ...      ...      class3
```

How do I get the information in there - or in the first place - don't lose them when I perform the extract?!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your shapefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always include and use example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))
p <- spPolygons(cds1, cds2)
p <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p, data.frame(class=c('A', 'B'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Now we can do:

```
v <- extract(r, p)
str(v)

#List of 2
# $ : num [1:38] 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 ...
# $ : num [1:25] 172 173 208 209 244 245 279 280 281 282 ...
```

Create a data.frame that has the polygon sequential ID and the extracted values

```
d <- data.frame(id=rep(1:length(v), sapply(v, length)), value=unlist(v))
```

(this particular approach using unlist only works for a single layer). For multiple layers do

```
#d <- data.frame(id=rep(1:length(v), sapply(v, length)), do.call(rbind, v))
```

Create a `data.frame` with the sequential ID and with the other polygon attributes required

```
pd <- cbind(id=1:length(p), data.frame(p))
```

Merge the two

```
m <- merge(pd, d)
```

Answer (score 1):

`?extract` indicates that the `sp` argument controls whether or not the extracted values should be added to the dataframe of the spatial object. Specifying `sp=TRUE` should do the trick. E.g.:

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
data(wrld_simpl)
r <- raster(extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), res=10)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
wrld_simpl_new <- extract(r, wrld_simpl, fun=mean, sp=TRUE)

head(wrld_simpl_new)

##     FIPS ISO2 ISO3 UN                NAME   AREA  POP2005 REGION SUBREGION     LON     LAT     layer
## ATG   AC   AG  ATG 28 Antigua and Barbuda     44    83039     19        29 -61.783  17.078 0.9142067
## DZA   AG   DZ  DZA 12             Algeria 238174 32854159      2        15   2.632  28.163 0.1774097
## AZE   AJ   AZ  AZE 31          Azerbaijan   8260  8352021    142       145  47.395  40.430 0.3098710
## ALB   AL   AL  ALB  8             Albania   2740  3153731    150        39  20.068  41.143 0.3746480
## ARM   AM   AM  ARM 51             Armenia   2820  3017661    142       145  44.563  40.534 0.3494729
## AGO   AO   AO  AGO 24              Angola 124670 16095214      2        17  17.544 -12.296 0.2873931
```

The added column has the name "layer", since that was the (default) name of the `RasterLayer`.

Comment: That requieres the `fun` argument to be set to something, such as `mean`. However, I only want to know which pixels lay in which raster. Imagine you have 100x100 pixel raster and there are two polygons. in one polygon there are 50 pixels, in the other 20. I want to write out which pixels are in which polygon!. Performing a `mean` would reduce all my pixels to one value.